# Create a sentence-term matrix using CountVectorizer()

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, sparse-matrix

I am trying to create a document-term matrix in Python based on the following list of sentences with the help of `CountVectorizer()`:

```py
tokens_sents = [
    'go local restaraunt yesterday evening try pasta .',
    'expect delicious , eatable .',
    'smell really bad delicious .',
    'never eat pasta restaraunt taste pasta awful']
```

I can get the desired outcome by processing sentences one by one (e.g. `tokens_sents[0]` ...) using `vectorizer.fit_transform()` as follows:

```py
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
import pandas as pd

vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform([tokens_sents[0],tokens_sents[1],tokens_sents[2]])   
df_bow_sklearn = pd.DataFrame(X.toarray(),columns=vectorizer.get_feature_names_out())
df_bow_sklearn.head()
```

which produces the result:

```
bad delicious   eatable evening expect  go  local   pasta   really  restaraunt  smell   try yesterday
0   0   0   0   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   0   1   1
1   0   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0
```

However, I wonder if there is a way to create this matrix by iteration, because usually there is a large number of sentences and simply writing them one by one isn't very convenient.

I tried this, but the iteration only processes the last sentence:

```py
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
import pandas as pd

vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
for i in range (0,len(tokens_sents)):
    X = vectorizer.fit_transform([tokens_sents[i]])
    i=i+1
df_bow_sklearn = pd.DataFrame(X.toarray(),columns=vectorizer.get_feature_names_out())
df_bow_sklearn.head()
```

which produces the result:

```
awful   eat never   pasta   restaraunt  taste
0   1   1   1   2   1   1
```

I am thinking maybe since `X` is a sparse matrix, there will be a way to append each vector by iteration?

Answer (score 0):

The term "*sentence-term matrix*" isn't used despite the fact you are working with sentences in your example. In most NLP tasks, each independent instance of text is referred to as a "document", even though it may only contain one sentence.

Based on this, and the content of your question, I presume you want to create a *document-term matrix* using `sklearn`'s `CountVectorizer`. Here is the code that will produce the output you desire (a `pandas` dataframe representing the document-term matrix, where column names are the features/vocabulary across all documents), without the need to loop over each sentence in your list, or manually pass each sentence as an argument to `fit_transform()` one by one.

### Solution

```py
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)  # Display all columns of dataframe

tokens_sents = [
    'go local restaraunt yesterday evening try pasta .',
    'expect delicious , eatable .',
    'smell really bad delicious .',
    'never eat pasta restaraunt taste pasta awful'
]

vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(tokens_sents)
df_bow_sklearn = pd.DataFrame(data=X.toarray(), columns=vectorizer.get_feature_names_out())
print(df_bow_sklearn.head())
```

### Output

```
   awful  bad  delicious  eat  eatable  evening  expect  go  local  never  pasta  really  restaraunt  smell  taste  try  yesterday
0      0    0          0    0        0        1       0   1      1      0      1       0           1      0      0    1          1
1      0    0          1    0        1        0       1   0      0      0      0       0           0      0      0    0          0
2      0    1          1    0        0        0       0   0      0      0      0       1           0      1      0    0          0
3      1    0          0    1        0        0       0   0      0      1      2       0           1      0      1    0          0
```